# Unable to get Xdebug 3 working with Docker

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, xdebug-3

So, after spending several days of browsing unsuccessfully trying to figure out why upgrading to Xdebug 3 seems to only partially work with my Dockerized Laravel project, here I am. I've closely followed the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) and official documentation, other [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65107145/docker-php-with-xdebug-3-env-xdebug-mode-doesnt-work) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553091/docker-php-fpm-plus-xdebug-config) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65137732/xdebug-v3-doesnt-stop-breakpoints-in-vscode), and am still completely befuddled as to why the debugger won't stop at breakpoints unless I manually pass in config options to run an Artisan command (more on this a bit below). Everything worked without issue with Xdebug 2.

Below are (what I think are) the relevant portions of config files/outputs. Yes, I realize the same configs are set multiple times, which is a result of trying many different locations to set these options.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: php
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: client_host=host.docker.internal client_port=9001 mode=debug start_with_request=yes
      XDEBUG_MODE: debug
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - v2
```

**php.dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql bcmath \
  && pecl install -f xdebug-3.0.1 \
  && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini;
```

My host (Windows) **php.ini** if relevant

```
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.1-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_port=9001
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9001,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_data": 65535,
                "show_hidden": 1,
                "max_children": 100,
                "max_depth": 5
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

The Xdebug section of **php -i** output (removed deprecated options)

```
Feature => Enabled/Disabled
Development Aids => ✘ disabled
Coverage => ✘ disabled
GC Stats => ✘ disabled
Profiler => ✘ disabled
Step Debugger => ✔ enabled
Tracing => ✘ disabled

Debugger => enabled
IDE Key =>  

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.client_discovery_header => no value => no value
xdebug.client_host => host.docker.internal => localhost
xdebug.client_port => 9001 => 9003
xdebug.cloud_id => no value => no value
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms => 200 => 200
xdebug.discover_client_host => Off => Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => no value => no value
xdebug.log => no value => no value
xdebug.log_level => 7 => 7
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.mode => develop => develop
xdebug.output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.start_upon_error => default => default
xdebug.start_with_request => default => default
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

Plus under **Additional modules**

```
XDEBUG_MODE => debug
XDEBUG_CONFIG => client_host=host.docker.internal client_port=9001 mode=debug start_with_request=yes
...
$_SERVER['XDEBUG_MODE'] => debug
$_SERVER['XDEBUG_CONFIG'] => client_host=host.docker.internal client_port=9001 mode=debug start_with_request=yes
...
$_ENV['XDEBUG_MODE'] => debug
$_ENV['XDEBUG_CONFIG'] => client_host=host.docker.internal client_port=9001 mode=debug start_with_request=yes
```

As I mentioned, running the options as flags on the CLI directly *does* respect the breakpoints I set -- that is, bashing into the php container and then running `php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes -dxdebug.client_port=9001 -dxdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1 artisan some:command` works with the debugger just fine.

Apologies for the length and for the file dump, but I'm truly lost at this point so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Looks like whatever issue I had was fixed in [Xdebug 3.0.2](https://xdebug.org/updates#x_3_0_2). Thanks to [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677909/unable-to-get-xdebug-3-working-with-docker#comment116132057_65677909) for the help!

Comment: CLI and your web server may be using different php.ini files (common these days on Linux and Mac). You can see what config files are parsed at the top of `php_info()` output. That's why you need to see at Xdebug info in a same way as you are trying to debug. **P.S.** You have `&& echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini;` -- why not put the rest of Xdebug config in the same manner instead of `XDEBUG_CONFIG: client_host=host....`. Anyway: try it as see how it goes.

Comment: I also suggest to enable and collect an Xdebug log and see what it will have to say: where it tries to connect to (if at all) and what the response is. In case if log is empty/no file created: 1) Xdebug is not even trying to debug (misconfig or does not see "debug me" flag) 2) File access permissions 3) Bad path (e.g. `/tmp/` on Ubuntu will be virtualized (per process?), better use `/var/log/...` sort of paths 4) SELinux or alike (which is unlikely to be the case for Docker images). **P.P.S.** Xdebug 3.0.2 is already available.

Comment: BTW -- your `php -i` shows `xdebug.start_with_request => default` .. while it is expected to be `yes`. So something does not add up somewhere. Definitely try writing Xdebug config in a file instead of ENV. BTW, you can store your xdebug.ini locally and copy it over (don't know if this is applicable for your images, but anyway: `RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug` `COPY ./ini/* /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/`

Comment: Thanks for the comments! `php_info()` output is the same as `php -i` as far as I can tell.

Comment: I actually did try the Xdebug config in the dockerfile as you suggested, but it didn't work (despite a clean build):

Comment: what I had was `RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql bcmath \
  && pecl install -f xdebug-3.0.1 \
  && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "client_port=9001" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
  && echo "start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini;`

Comment: Wouldn't there be an issue copying my host PHP config to the container's since I'm on Windows and the container runs Ubuntu? Or are you suggesting specifying just the relevant xdebug configs in a local ini file and then appending the contents to something in the container?

Comment: Okay, it seems that upgrading to 3.0.2 did the trick! No idea which of the fixes on the updates page did the trick, but thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Yes, specify whatever is needed for the project in xdebug.ini, keep it local (so it's easy to edit etc) and copy the file into the image on build (instead of making it dynamically via multiple `echo` statements). May not work if you making the Xdebug extension name dynamically `echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)"` and not via `docker-php-ext-enable xdebug`. **Anyway:** do whatever is needed/can be done to get `xdebug.start_with_request => yes`

Comment: Well, FWIW `xdebug.start_with_request` is still set to `default` but it seems to be working now?

Comment: As long as it works... BTW: 3.0.2 has some changes in how some values are treated, `start_with_request` in particular (https://bugs.xdebug.org/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=00001925), could be related.

Comment: Yup, saw that and didn't think it applied at the time but in retrospect that seems likely.