# Unable to get Xdebug 3 working with Laravel Sail, Docker and Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, laravel, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I've spent hours and hours trying everything I or Google could think of, but Xdebug doesn't stop on any breakpoints.

Also had a look at this question and answers but still... no luck:
[Unable to get Xdebug 3 working with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677909/unable-to-get-xdebug-3-working-with-docker)

In the past it worked, but somehow it stopped working. Maybe an update of docker or whatever package / app caused it to stop.

On macOS:

- deleted docker, reinstalled it with the newest version (4.8.1 78998).
- removed my current Laravel Sail project and created a new Laravel Sail project through `curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash`
- added `SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug` to the newly created .env file
- `sail up -d` to start everything
- removed and reinstalled Visual Studio Code newest version: 1.6.7.1
- created a PHP launch.json file with the following contents:

  ```json
  {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
          {
              "name": "Listen for Sail Xdebug",
              "type": "php",
              "request": "launch",
              "port": 9003,
              "pathMappings": {
                  "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
              },
              "hostname": "localhost",
              "ignore": [
                  "**/vendor/**/*.php"
              ],
              "xdebugSettings": {
                  "max_data": 65536,
                  "show_hidden": 1,
                  "max_children": 100,
                  "max_depth": 3
              }
          }
      ]
  }
  ```
- got the following message inside of VSCode:

  > 'Cannot validate since a PHP installation could not be found. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable.'

  I don't know if this is the problem or what I should do since I'm using docker.
- placed a breakpoint in the route file or whatever else file that you create
- inside of the 'Run and Debug' tab of VSCode I told it to use config 'Listen for Sail Xdebug' and run the debugger (F5) -> I checked all checkboxes for breakpoints (notices, warnings, errors ...)

Nothing happens. VSCode does not stop on any breakpoint.

I still have no idea where to look as to get it working again.

I would be very happy if someone, maybe Derick himself, could help me out here. The last hairs that I still have are about to pulled out :O

Please let me know if you need any more information, settings or code from me!

- PHP version 8.1.5
- Xdebug version 3.1.2

`xdebug_info()` says:

```
Version 3.1.2
Support Xdebug on Patreon, GitHub, or as a business
Enabled Features
(through 'XDEBUG_MODE' env variable)
Feature Enabled/Disabled    Docs
Development Helpers ✔ enabled   
Coverage    ✘ disabled  
GC Stats    ✘ disabled  
Profiler    ✘ disabled  
Step Debugger   ✔ enabled   
Tracing ✘ disabled  
Optional Features
Compressed File Support no
Clock Source    clock_gettime
Diagnostic Log
No messages
Step Debugging  Docs
Debugger    Not Active  
PHP
Build Configuration
Version (Run Time)  8.1.5
Version (Compile Time)  8.1.1
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Settings
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/8.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-imap.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-ldap.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pcov.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/25-swoole.ini, /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
Directive   Local Value Master Value    Docs
xdebug.mode (through XDEBUG_MODE)   develop,debug   develop 
xdebug.start_with_request   default default 
xdebug.start_upon_error default default 
xdebug.output_dir   /tmp    /tmp    
xdebug.use_compression  0   0   
xdebug.trigger_value    no value    no value    
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value    
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value    
xdebug.log  no value    no value    
xdebug.log_level    7   7   
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128 
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512 
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3   
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256 
xdebug.cli_color    0   0   
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off 
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0   
xdebug.halt_level   0   0   
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1  
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off 
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value    
xdebug.dump_globals On  On  
xdebug.dump_once    On  On  
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off 
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p   
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off 
xdebug.cloud_id no value    no value    
xdebug.client_host  host.docker.internal    localhost   
xdebug.client_port  9003    9003    
xdebug.discover_client_host Off Off 
xdebug.client_discovery_header  no value    no value    
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value    
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms   200 200 
xdebug.scream   Off Off 
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p  
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c    
xdebug.trace_format 0   0   
xdebug.trace_options    0   0   
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off 
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
```

Comment: It is spelled "Derick".

Comment: I am sorry, i will spell it correctly next time.

Answer (score 10):

---

I had the same problem. I have fixed this issue by updating php.ini file of docker.
To update php.ini of you sail docker you have to follow this steps

1. run :

### ./vendor/bin/sail artisan sail:publish

This will create docker folder in root of your project.

2. update php.ini of docker/8.1 folder. Add this code in php.ini

---

```html
[XDebug]
    zend_extension = xdebug.so
    xdebug.mode = debug
    xdebug.start_with_request = yes
    xdebug.discover_client_host = true
    xdebug.idekey = VSC
    xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal
    xdebug.client_port = 9003
```

3. Refresh sail docker container with:

   ./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache
4. add following line to .env file

SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug

5. run docker and enjoy your xdebug with vscode.

Comment: The answer is good, however, I had to add the following line to launch.json as well:

"pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
 }

Comment: See my comment [here](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/426#issuecomment-1404067301) on how I got it working using VSCode without having to publish the docker files

Answer (score 2):

When trying to set this up I add  `"log": true,` to my launch.json file to see whether there are errors or useful information.

Another useful tool is the `sail root-shell` command, which acts similar as `docker exec -it /bin/bash`. This allows you to execute commands in the container, such as `printenv` to check if your environment variables are set correctly.

The following made it work for me:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "hostname": "0.0.0.0",
            "log": true, 
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}",

            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Add these two to your .env file. These are the only two variables which are recognized by the `artisan serve` command (which powers sail) as of Laravel version 8.53.0 so there is no point in adding additional variables.

```
XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug,coverage
XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=host.docker.internal"
```

Edit:
In the newer versions of laravel you have to use different environment variables:

```
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=debug,develop,coverage
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=host.docker.internal"
```

I added the php XDebugHelper extension to chrome aswell.

You can check if your Xdebug instance is running in your sail container via `sail php -v`, your output should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: give me error xdebug_info :[Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Sail should work straight out of the box. I have made a 5 minute [video](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#related_content) titled "Laravel Sail with PhpStorm", but it should work equally well with VS Code with the configuration that you outlined.

To find out why something does not work, you can either try debugging a file that has `xdebug_info()` in it. It will tell you whether (and if) Xdebug tried making a connection, to where, and what the result was. There are also links to the documentation directly next to each error message (if present).

Your log says:

> Diagnostic Log
> No messages

Which means that you did not instruct Xdebug to start a debugging session through a trigger. You need to tell Xdebug to start one. The [Laravel Sail documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail#xdebug-browser-usage) points to the [Xdebug documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#web-application) on how to do this. It recommends you use one of the mentioned browser extensions to "click" when you want to debug or not.

If you need more debugging information, make a log file and crank it up to 10: `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=10`.

Comment: i looked at xdebug_info(), but what exactly should i look for? I see a lot of information, but what is relevant? I looked that the port (9003) which i also have in my vscode launch.json file, so that should be correct. And i do not know if you know/work with laravel, but do you know where i should place the lines that you mentioned in your last comment?

Comment: i have added the contents of xdebug_info() to the start post. i read that xdebug.start_with_request should be set to 'yes'. Does anyone know where i would put that when using laravel sail (thus using docker)? Google topics only mention it, but i have no idea where to put it. Also mentioned, i have no idea how i would get the logging information for your last comment 'If you need more debugging information, make a log file and crank it up to 10: xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log and xdebug.log_level=10.'. where do these go? into which file?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you trying to get Laravel Sail, XDebug and VS Code to cooperate for debugging on a newly created Laravel project on Linux although it should work as it is with just adding `SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug` in the .env file. It didn't work until I also added `SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=localhost"` in the .env file. I didn't have to change anything in the default launch.json that was created automatically from VS Code. Just remember to restart VS Code to lauch the docker containers with the new configuration.

Comment: Thx for showing your solution and good to hear that it solved your problem!